# Can not trigger onclick function using Django, Python and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have an issue. I could not trigger the `onclick` event on the link using Django and Python. I am providing my code below.

base.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var query='';
      function pageTransition(){
        var full_url = window.location.search;
        var url = full_url.replace("?", '');
        query=url.file;
        console.log('query',query);
        var url="'"+query+"'";
        $.getScript(url,function(){
           $('a').velocity("scroll", { duration: 1000 });
        })
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Nuclear Reactor</h1>
      {% if count > 0  %}
      <b>Hi, {{ user.username }}</b>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}?file=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js" onclick="pageTransition();">Home</a>
        <a href="{% url 'view_reactor' %}?file=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js" onclick="pageTransition();">View Reactor status</a>
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> / <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
      {% endif %}
      <hr>
    </header>
    <main>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<center><h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>This App allow to control the life cycle of the Nuclear Reactor and Retrive the status report </p>
<p><a href="{% url 'status' %}">Status report</a><a href="{% url 'control' %}">Control panel</a></p>
</center>

{% endblock %}
```

total html generated output after click on home link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var query='';
      function pageTransition(){
        var full_url = window.location.search;
        var url = full_url.replace("?", '');
        query=url.file;
        console.log('query',query);
        var url="'"+query+"'";
        $.getScript(url,function(){
           $('a').velocity("scroll", { duration: 1000 });
        })
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Nuclear Reactor</h1>

      <b>Hi, </b>
        <a href="/home/?file=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js" onclick="pageTransition();">Home</a>
        <a href="/view_reactor/?file=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js" onclick="pageTransition();">View Reactor status</a>
        <a href="/logout/">logout</a>

      <hr>
    </header>
    <main>

<center><h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>This App allow to control the life cycle of the Nuclear Reactor and Retrive the status report </p>
<p><a href="/status/">Status report</a><a href="/control/">Control panel</a></p>
</center>


    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I need to get that query string value and include it inside that JavaScript function but the JavaScript function is not called at all.

Comment: Could you show the HTML code once rendered on your browser? Also, show the output of the script console on the browser.

Comment: I have written the console inside that function but its not coming at all.

Comment: @VMRuiz : I have posted the total html content.

Comment: You are posting the content of the django template before rendering, not the HTML final output. The javascript code seems to be alright but maybe something is not being render as you expected. Please, load this page on your browser an copy here the html code you get.

Comment: @VMRuiz : I posted one of the rendering page `i.e-home.html`.

Comment: @VMRuiz : Actually my first html code is base code which is including in each page.

Comment: Those are not HTML code, those are Django Templates (which happens to contains parts of HTML).  Are you getting their contents from your browser or from the project files? Please, open your browser and load the webpage that will make this template to used, then copy here the HTML from the web browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154291/discussion-between-satya-and-vmruiz).